# Computing the convex conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let
$$
F(r, x) = \frac{1}{2}\| r\|^2_2 + \lambda \| x\|_1 + \langle y, Ax - b - r\rangle,
$$
where $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $b, r, y \in \mathbb R^m$ and $\lambda > 0$

Considering that $x$ is constant, find the convex conjugate of $F$

This is my work so far:
\begin{align*}
F^*(z) &= \sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - F(u))\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\| u\|^2_2 - \langle y, Ax - b - u\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1)\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle + \langle y, u\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1)\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle) - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle + \langle y, u\rangle) - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z + y , u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle) - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1\\
&= \sup_{u}\left( \frac{1}{2}\| z + y \|_2^2 -\frac{1}{2}(\| u - (z + y)\|_2^2\right) - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\|z+y \|^2_2 - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1,
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure sure because of the supremum and $x$ being constant.

Comment: This looks fine to me (the constants are treated like constants, the supremum is quite clearly worked out). Do you have some more specific doubts?

Comment: Brackets are not consistent in 4th and 6th line, otherwise looks good.